# OneLogin Python SDK log_user_out() not working

Tags: onelogin

I am trying to implement the Python SDK to log a user out. However, it is not working as expected. It returns `False` and does not log the user out even though I am passing valid parameters. According to the documentation, it will return `True` on a success.

I also tested with curl using the same parameters and API credentials. That worked as expected.

I am referencing the Python SDK documentation for `log_user_out(self, user_id)`:

https://onelogin.github.io/onelogin-python-sdk/v2/api.client.html

And for CURL:

https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/log-user-out

### Python Test

I use the SDK to query for a user, then use that user's ID to log the user out but it returns `False`. I am logged in as the test user in a browser and the user is not logged off. I then grab the token to use in the following curl command test.

```
>>> onelogin_client = OneLoginClient(client_id, client_secret)
>>> 
>>> onelogin_client.get_access_token()
<onelogin.api.models.onelogin_token.OneLoginToken object at 0x10e319970>
>>> 
>>> query_parameters = {"email": "aaatestuserbob@eou.edu"}
>>> users = onelogin_client.get_users(query_parameters)
>>> 
>>> print(users[0])
User :  {'id': 179124057, 'external_id': None, 'email': 'aaatestuserbob@eou.edu', 'username': 'aaatestuserbob@eou.edu', 'firstname': 'Bobby', 'lastname': 'Lasterson', 'distinguished_name': 'redacted', 'phone': None, 'company': '', 'department': '', 'title': '', 'status': 1, 'member_of': '', 'samaccountname': 'aaatestuserbob', 'userprincipalname': '', 'group_id': 442079, 'role_ids': [], 'custom_attributes': {}, 'openid_name': '', 'locale_code': '', 'comment': '', 'directory_id': 50400, 'manager_ad_id': None, 'trusted_idp_id': None, 'manager_user_id': None, 'activated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 18, 9, 21, 159000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 18, 9, 21, 164000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 10, 21, 14, 31, 835000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'password_changed_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 18, 9, 21, 102000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'invitation_sent_at': None, 'invalid_login_attempts': 0, 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 10, 21, 14, 31, 580000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'locked_until': None, 'state': 1}
>>> 
>>> print(users[0].id)
179124057
>>> 
>>> id = users[0].id
>>> 
>>> onelogin_client.log_user_out(id)
False
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print(onelogin_client.get_access_token())
OneLoginToken :  {'access_token': 'redacted_access_token', 'refresh_token': 'redacted_refresh_token', 'account_id': redacted_account_id, 'token_type': 'bearer', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 13, 15, 4, 33, 753000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'expires_in': 36000}
>>>
```

### CURL Test

Using the same API credentials that I just used in the Python Test I get the expected results using CURL. The response shows `success` and the test user is signed out of the browser.

```
➜  ~ curl 'https://eou.onelogin.com/api/1/users/179124057/logout' \
-X PUT \
-H "Authorization: bearer: redacted_access_token"
{"status":{"error":false,"code":200,"type":"success","message":"Success"}}%
➜  ~
```

Why does this work with CURL but not the Python SDK? Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks for your help.

## EDIT

Some additional information... I took a look at the SDK code and found the error attributes. Below are the results. It looks like an exception was raised. It appears to be a `JSONDecodeError`.

https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-python-sdk/blob/d752664dfe71243c3b7a8120a0f3abffb0f51010/src/onelogin/api/client.py#L937

```
>>> onelogin_client.error
500
>>> 
>>> onelogin_client.error_description
'Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'
>>> 
>>> onelogin_client.error_attribute
>>>
```

Also, I realized the SDK uses a different API URL than is recommended here: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/log-user-out

eou.onelogin.com vs api.us.onelogin.com

The URL that the SDK uses also works with curl.

```
➜  ~ curl 'https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users/179124057/logout' \
-X PUT \
-H "Authorization: bearer: redacted_access_token"
{"status":{"error":false,"code":200,"type":"success","message":"Success"}}%
➜  ~
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question directly, but there are a couple of things that can fix these issues.
The python sdk you linked uses the deprecated Onelogin API. It also uses python2. Using python3 sdk against the version 2 API shouldn't have the issues you're experiencing.